# Set the row background color of html table depending on row index

Tags: html, css

I have a GridView where the ItemTempate contains an HTML table. I am trying to set the class of the table row depending on the GridViewRow Index as follows.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="tblAlternate">
<tr class="<%#(Container.RowIndex+1)%2==0?"CustomBGColor":"WhiteBGColor"%>">
              ....                         
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: you could do this with plain css-selectors

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: It's exactly like @SW4 shows it in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `nth-child` CSS selector, e.g:

```
.tblAlternate tr:nth-child(1){
  background:red;
}
.tblAlternate tr:nth-child(4){
  background:green;
}
```

Where the number is index+1 (e.g. it starts from 1 not 0)

In your code it looks like you're coding for odd vs even rows, so you could use:

```
.tblAlternate tr:nth-child(odd){
  background:red;
}
.tblAlternate tr:nth-child(even){
  background:green;
}
```

[**More on `nth-child` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

> The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
>   or zero value for n, and has a parent element.
>
> This can more clearly be described this way: the matching element is
>   the bth child of an element after all its children have been split
>   into groups of a elements each.
>
> Among other things, this allows selectors to match every other row in
>   a table.